# How to configure AWS S3 SDK for Node.JS to be used with localhost?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to use [fakes3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) as an endpoint for some simple S3 code I've written. I can't get beyond the connection stage though.

The current error is: `NetworkingError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`.

I've got configuration setup:

```
"aws": {                                
    "accessKeyId": "123",               
    "secretAccessKey": "abc",           
    "region": "",                       
    "endpoint": "http://localhost:8081",
    "sslEnabled": false                 
}               

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// loaded the config into an object called `config`:

AWS.config.update(config.aws);
s3 = new AWS.S3();
// also tried creating an `EndPoint`:
s3.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(config.aws.endpoint);
```

When I try simple code like:

```
s3.putObject({ Bucket: 'logging', Key: "logging123", Body: "started" }, 
   function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
       console.log(err);
   }
});
```

The error mentioned above occurs. When I leave out directly setting the `endPoint`, the request is made to the East AWS region (and ignores the `endpoint` value I've passed in via configuration).

And, I'm running `fakes3` using the command line:

```
fakes3 -r c:\temp\_fakes3 -p 8081
Loading FakeS3 with c:/temp/_fakes3 on port 8081 with hostname s3.amazonaws.com
[2013-11-30 14:20:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-11-30 14:20:22] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]
[2013-11-30 14:20:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11800 port=8081
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the AWS SDK [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html) there is the following option:

s3ForcePathStyle (boolean)

> Returns whether to force path style URLs for S3 objects

I've tested it works with this config:

```
var config = {
  accessKeyId: "123",
  secretAccessKey: "abc",
  endpoint: "localhost:3000",
  sslEnabled: false,
  s3ForcePathStyle: true
};
AWS.config.update(config);
s3Client = new AWS.S3();
```

Comment: Would somebody clarify what "force path style URLs" means?

Comment: adam-beck, i think it's to force urls like http://{host}/{bucket}/{key} instead of http://{bucket}.{host}/{key}

Comment: @adam-beck Mark is right: when set to `true` it forces `http://{host}/{bucket}/{key}` paths. This might be a lifesaver when e.g. configuring SSL for random subdomains.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the aws sdk version 3. The config structure has changed and `s3ForcePathStyle` is now renamed to `forcePathStyle`

```
const { S3 } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const config = {
          "credentials": {
            "accessKeyId": "minioadmin",
            "secretAccessKey": "minioadmin"
          },
          "endpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:9099",
          "sslEnabled": false,
          "forcePathStyle": true
    };
const s3Client = new S3(config);

// example of usage
const response = await s3Client.listObjectsV2({
      Bucket: 'bucketname',
      Prefix: 'prefix'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The request is being sent to:

```
logging.127.0.0.1:8081
```

The '"logging"` is the bucket name (which makes sense as the SDK for S3 always sends the bucket as part of the URL). As that name doesn't properly resolve to the computer, it was failing.

So, instead try using a simple dynamic DNS from 37signals and change the configuration  to be:

```
"endpoint": "127.0.0.1.xip.io:8081/"
```

In total:

```
"aws": {                                
    "accessKeyId": "123",               
    "secretAccessKey": "abc",           
    "region": "",                       
    "endpoint": "127.0.0.1.xip.io:8081/",
    "sslEnabled": false                 
}
```

There may be other options for this, but http://xip.io grabs the IP address from the subdomain and always returns that. So, in the case above, the actual `url` sent is: `"logging.127.0.0.1.xip.io"`, but the DNS server at xip.io returns `127.0.0.1`.

I could have edited and maintained local DNS files, but this was a simple solution that was clean enough for my purposes.

*In order to track this issue down, I looked at the source code, and in particular the file `node.js` in the `handleRequest` function, which is where the actual http request was being sent.*