# Uploading to amazon s3 using node.js server works only once

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So here's the code I use to upload an image to the server, but it only works once

[answer in the comments of the accepted answer]

1. I don't know if I'm supposed to set the endpoint at all, all the examples on the s3 tutorials don't even mention endpoints
2. I am not sure if I'm supposed to keep making new s3 objects for each file to upload
3. If I don't set the endpoint, upload always fails even on the first try (and gives the same console output as the second upload posted below)

The upload function works once so I think that means I set credentials correctly.
But the only way to get it working again is to restart the node.js app.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing a lot of things.
In particular I noticed that on the second upload, the s3 object wants to connect to localhost instead of the endpoint url that I explicitly set for it when I made it.

```js
function upload_photo(socket, data) {
 s3 = new AWS.S3( {endpoint: 'http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'} );
 
 console.log("s3 endpoint", s3.endpoint); // for testing

 var myBucket = 'blackjack-profilepics'; 
 var myKey = socket.player.user_id +".txt";

 params = {Bucket: 'blackjack-profilepics', Key: myKey, Body: data };
 s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err) {
  console.log("Error uploading data:",err)
  console.log("s3 endpoint", s3.endpoint);
 } else {
  console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/%s", myKey);
 }
  });
```

And here's the console output for the first and succeeding upload attempts:

```html
first upload:
0|blackjac | s3 endpoint Endpoint {
0|blackjac |   protocol: 'http:',
0|blackjac |   host: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
0|blackjac |   port: 80,
0|blackjac |   hostname: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
0|blackjac |   pathname: '/',
0|blackjac |   path: '/',
0|blackjac |   href: 'http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/' }
0|blackjac | done with upload!
0|blackjac | Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/15.txt

second upload:
0|blackjac | s3 endpoint Endpoint {
0|blackjac |   protocol: 'http:',
0|blackjac |   host: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
0|blackjac |   port: 80,
0|blackjac |   hostname: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
0|blackjac |   pathname: '/',
0|blackjac |   path: '/',
0|blackjac |   href: 'http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/' }
0|blackjac | done with upload!
0|blackjac | Error uploading data: { UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `blackjack-profilepics.localhost'. This service may not be available in the `ap-southeast-1' region.
0|blackjac |     at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:456:46)
0|blackjac |     at Request.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
0|blackjac |     at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
0|blackjac |     at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
0|blackjac |     at ClientRequest.error (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:295:22)
0|blackjac |     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:89:19)
0|blackjac |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
0|blackjac |     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
0|blackjac |     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
0|blackjac |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
0|blackjac |   message: 'Inaccessible host: `blackjack-profilepics.localhost\'. This service may not be available in the `ap-southeast-1\' region.',
0|blackjac |   code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
0|blackjac |   region: 'ap-southeast-1',
0|blackjac |   hostname: 'blackjack-profilepics.localhost',
0|blackjac |   retryable: true,
0|blackjac |   originalError:
0|blackjac |    { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND blackjack-profilepics.localhost blackjack-profilepics.localhost:8000
0|blackjac |        at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
0|blackjac |        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
0|blackjac |      message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND blackjack-profilepics.localhost blackjack-profilepics.localhost:8000',
0|blackjac |      code: 'NetworkingError',
0|blackjac |      errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
0|blackjac |      syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
0|blackjac |      hostname: 'blackjack-profilepics.localhost',
0|blackjac |      host: 'blackjack-profilepics.localhost',
0|blackjac |      port: 8000,
0|blackjac |      region: 'ap-southeast-1',
0|blackjac |      retryable: true,
0|blackjac |      time: 2018-06-10T22:15:58.926Z },
0|blackjac |   time: 2018-06-10T22:15:58.926Z }
0|blackjac | s3 endpoint Endpoint {
0|blackjac |   protocol: 'http:',
0|blackjac |   host: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
0|blackjac |   port: 80,
0|blackjac |   hostname: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
0|blackjac |   pathname: '/',
0|blackjac |   path: '/',
0|blackjac |   href: 'http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the second upload it seems that it's trying to look for your bucket on the `localhost` domain. Could you try specifying the region rather than the endpoint?

The S3 service object should feed that information into the endpoint either way.

```
s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'ap-southeast-1'})
```

Comment: Tried your code, but because it doesn't specify the endpoint - it tries to look for the bucket on the localhost domain again
(just like in the second upload)

Comment: Could you add the piece of code where you declare the AWS object please?

Comment: When you asked about the AWS object declaration, I looked at the config.json file that I loaded values from
There was an item in the JSON:
"endpoint": "http://localhost:8000"
that caused this entire problem
Problem solved, answer accepted

Comment: For future visitors have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27796925/558287

In the v3 sdk, the config `forcePathStyle: true` fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, this config worked for me.

```
const bucketname = 'bsbucket';
//configuring the aws environment
aws.config.update({
    region:"us-west-1",
    accessKeyId:"<accessKeyId>",
    secretAccessKey:"<secretAccessKey>",
    s3BucketEndpoint:true,
    endpoint:"http://" + bucketname + ".s3.amazonaws.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this most of the time, but sometimes not the first time. Turns out I was also using dynamodb-connect which updated the global AWS config internally. You may not be using this package but perhaps add a breakpoint in AWS.config.update and/or AWS.config.loadFromPath (in v2 of the SDK).